# Simple Serial Connector for Java

Tags: java, serial-port

I am using the Java Simple Serial Connector to communicate with a Data Card Embossing machine.   Below is my program which is based on the example provided by the author.  Here is the problem that we are encountering.  If we send over one  label to the embosser, nothing happens.  If we send a second label to the embosser, the first label prints.  If we send a third label, then the second label prints and so on.  The vendor of the program provides code in Turbo "C".  In the Turbo "C" program, the "C" program executes these two commands at the end of transmission.

```
clear_serial_queue()
restore_serialint()
```

In my Java program, I am using `serialPort.closePort()`.

Is there anything else that I might try to force the embosser to print immediately rather than on the next request?  We have been working on this for several days without any success.

Java Program :

```
/**
* Construct the class from the name of a serial port; e.g., COM1
*
* @param  Name of the com port to use.
*/
public SerialTester(String name) throws Exception {

   serialPort = new SerialPort(name);
   try {
        serialPort.openPort();//Open serial port
        serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600, 
                             SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                             SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                             SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);//Set params. Also you can set params by this string: serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);

   }
   catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

/**
* This method reads the file and sends its contents to the serial
* port.
*
* @param  fileName  Name of the file containing the data to send.
*
* @return  Number of bytes send.
*/
public int sendFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

   // Read until the end of the buffer is reached.
   int byteCount = 0;
   BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
   String str = "";
   String str1 = "";

   try {
      while ((str1 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         byteCount += str1.length();
         str += str1+"\n";
      }
      reader.close();

      // Delay for one second.
      waitForDevice(1000);

      if (serialPort != null) {
         serialPort.writeBytes(str.getBytes());//Write data to port
         serialPort.closePort();//Close serial port
      }
   }
   catch (SerialPortException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
    }   

    return byteCount;
}

/**
 * This method adds the specified number of milliseconds as a delay.
 *
 * @param  Time in milliseconds.
 */
 private void waitForDevice(long delay) {

      // Wait the specified delay time.
      try {
         Thread.sleep(delay);
      } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }

 }

/**
* This is the main routine used for testing purposes.
*
* @param   args[0]  Complete path name of the file to send.
* @param   args[1]  Name of the com port to use.
*/
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   int count = 0;

   // If the file name is null, then report an error.
   if (args.length == 0) {
      System.out.println("First argument must specified the name of the file to send.");
   }
   else if (args.length == 1) {
      SerialTester tester = new SerialTester();
      count = tester.sendFile(args[0]);
      System.out.println("Total bytes read: "+count);

   }
   else if (args.length == 2) {
      SerialTester tester = new SerialTester("COM1");
      count = tester.sendFile(args[0]);
      System.out.println("Total bytes sent: "+count);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a form-feed as the last character.  You might also want to use a `StringBuilder` for a little more efficiency:

```
public int sendFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
   // Read until the end of the buffer is reached.
   int byteCount = 0;
   BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   try {
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         byteCount += line.length();
         sb.append(line).append('\n');
      }
      reader.close();
      sb.append('\f');       // <<<<-- The form feed

      // Delay for one second.
      waitForDevice(1000);   // <<<<-- why delay here?  try delaying after writeBytes().

      if (serialPort != null) {
         serialPort.writeBytes(str.getBytes());//Write data to port
         serialPort.closePort();//Close serial port
      }
   }
   catch (SerialPortException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
   }   

   return byteCount;
}
```

BTW, you're not really counting bytes (not that it matters), because readLine() could be throwing away CR/LF pairs rather than just LF or CR, additionally you are counting the string length but then adding a `\n` to the buffer, so the actual bytes sent to the device is a little different.  As I said, not that it matters.